# visual studio express 2012 web cannot connect to Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

is there any bug when connecting visual studio express 2012 web that is installed on windows 7 to connect to SQL Server Express 2012 or 2008R2?

the error message is this:

```
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> is not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server name is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
> SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified.)
```

in my situation, VS connects to SQL only if from server OS to Server OS

or it is from win7 OS to win7 OS ?

here is the scenario I got in my environment : 
we have 4 machines

1-win2012Srv:
-Virtual machine 
-windows 2012 serverSQL Server Express 2012 visual studio express 2012 web
-Symantec antivirus (disabled)
-firewall is disabled
-Static IP address

2- win08r2srv:
-Virtual machine 
-windows 2008 R2 server
-SQL Express 2008 R2
-visual studio express 2012 web
-no antivirus 
-firewall is disabled
-Static IP address

3- Win7PC1:
-Real machine (PC) 
-windows 7
-SQL Express 2012
-visual studio express 2012 web
-Avast antivirus (removed already)
-firewall is disabled
-Dynamic IP address

4- Win7PC2:
-Real machine (PC) 
-windows 7
-visual studio express 2012 web
-Avast antivirus (Running)
-firewall is disabled
-Dynamic IP address

the result is:

```
> Legend :) 
> 
> VS = visual studio express 2012 web
> --> = connect (i.e. I can connect to the SQL Server database)
> X--> = cannot connect (i.e. cannot add database connection)
```

vs on win2012Srv  -->   SQL on win08r2srv

vs on win08r2srv  -->   SQL on win2012Srv

vs on Win7PC1     X--> SQL on win2012Srv

vs on Win7PC1     X--> SQL on win08r2srv

vs on Win7PC2     X--> SQL on win2012Srv

vs on Win7PC2     X--> SQL on win08r2srv

vs on Win7PC2     ---> SQL on Win7PC1

thanks

Hasan

Comment: I used these articles to configure the SQL server:

stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate your valuable inputs. My hair about to fall because of this problem :(

Tom, thanks, I have gone through that article weeks ago, but no luck :)

The Summary:

I have made a work around to resolve my problem. I have created a new virtual server on the second physical DELL server (with SQL Express 2012).

The problem seems to be a network issue on the hyper-V virtual switch!!

More details:

As described previously, VS connects to SQL service within the same Hyper-V only, although all configuration are right. From any PC within my domain, I can connect to the SQL server on the first Hyper-V service using the ODBC or the connection string file (.UDL), BUT not through the “visual studio express 2012 web” !!!!!!!!!

Now, I can connect from any PC (using visual studio express 2012 web) to any SQL server Express 2012 on the second Hyper-V .

I have made 4 virtual service on the first hyperV and 4 on the second HyperV. All with the same result:

- •VS on PC’s can connect normally to any SQL server on the second
  HyperV•VS on PC’s can NOT connect to any SQL server on the first
  HyperV
- •VS on virtual servers on first HyperV can connect normally to any
  SQL server on the same physical machine/Same hyperV .
- •VS on virtual servers on first HyperV can connect normally to any
  SQL server on the second physical machine/Second hyperV .
- •VS on virtual servers on the second HyperV can connect to any SQL
  server on PC’s or on the second HyperV/Same physical machine.
- •VS on virtual servers on the second HyperV can NOT connect SQL
  servers on the first HyperV

Long story that last more than one month :(